# Determine Duplicate data using LINQ to EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have a dataset that i want to groupby to determine duplicate data.

Example i have a dataset that looks like this.

```
|id  |  Number  | ContactID  
 1      1234        5       
 2      9873        6
 3      1234        7
 4      9873        6
```

Now i want to select data that has more than one occurrence of Number but only if the ContactID is not the same.

So basically return

```
| Number | Count |
   1234      2
```

Any help would be appreciated using LINQ to EF, thanks.

Comment: So you want to group by a concatenation of Number and Contact ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query avoids making a custom `IEqualityComparer` as if I remember correctly don't think they play well with EF.

```
var results = data.GroupBy(number => number.Number)
                  .Where(number => number.Count() > 1)
                  .Select(number => new
                  {
                      Number = number.Key,
                      Count = number.GroupBy(contactId => contactId.ContactId).Count(x => x.Count() == 1)
                  })
                  .Where(x => x.Count > 0).ToList();
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/45BepU)

It does an initial `GroupBy` to get all `Numbers` that are duplicated. It then selects a new type that contains the number and a second `GroupBy` that groups by `ContactId` then counts all groups with exactly one entry. Then it takes all results whose count is greater than zero.

Have not testing it against EF, but the query uses only standard Linq operators so EF shouldn't have any issues translating it.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

All thanks to @DrCopyPaste, as he told me that I misunderstood your problem. Here is the correct solution:-

```
  var result = from c in db.list
               group c by c.Number into g
               let count = g.GroupBy(x => x.ContactID).Where(x => x.Count() == 1).Count()
               where count != 0
               select new
                     {
                         Number = g.Key,
                         Count = count
                     };
```

[Sample Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zz46OP)

Comment: I think you ignored the part where it says that `ContactID is not the same`, but only `Number` is; so grouping by both is not the solution.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste - Because of that statement we are grouping by both i.e. `Number` & `ContactId`, so that it will produce duplicates if ContactID is **not same**.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste - Added a fiddle for reference.

Comment: The requested result was `Number: 1234; Count: 2`, okay Count is trivial, but you return `Number: 9873, ContactId: 6`

Comment: @DrCopyPaste - Thanks a lot buddy, you were correct. I have updated the code.

Comment: glad we cleared that up ;) Ah one thing, you should delete first paragraph and last fiddle, that could confuse some ppl.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this(using 1 level of grouping):

```
var results = data
              .Where(x => data.Any(y => y.Id != x.Id && y.Number == x.Number && y.ContactId != x.ContactId))
              .GroupBy(x => x.Number)
              .Select(grp => new { Number = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() })
              .ToList();
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iQ40Lu)